# Android - How to read random data from imported database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, random

I already read a lot of answers to similar questions, but seems that none od those answers solve my problem.

I copied a SQLite database to the "Asset" folder of my application, and I imported it with this code found on a website (I didn't understood everything in this code btw):

```
package com.example.quizone_2;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.quizone_2/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "QuizOne_DB";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the     application assets and resources.
     * @param context
      */
    public DataBase(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

  /**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //Do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
   // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
   // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

My database contain a table that contains questions and answers.

Now, what I want, is to search for a random question to display in an activity, and than compare the answer (true or false) with the answer in the database.

The problem is that I didn't find anything similar on the web, in first place because my database is imported and not created in the app, and in second place because I didn't really understood how to read data from my database. Not to mention that I don't even know how to random the search.

Thank you if you read the question entirely, and I hope someone could help me, because I don't really know where to start.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One alternative:
1) Assign a numeric id to each question in the table. (from 1 to n where n is number of questions)
2) In your activity generate a random number between 1 and n. You can use Math.round((Math.random()*n)+1) to do this. 
3) Then you query your table where the numeric id (point 1) equals the random number.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. And how can I do this? I mean, talking about code, how can I compare the random number with the id of a row? And then how can I take the text in the corresponding row? Sorry if I need a lot of help